# Coldfusion 8 all scheduled tasks stopped

Tags: coldfusion, scheduled-tasks, coldfusion-8

I have 15 to 20 scheduled tasks running 24/7. Everything worked great for months and suddenly all tasks stopped.

When I create new task that new task works great.

When I pause and resume old task nothing happens.

When I *delete* an old task and create exactly the same task with exactly the same name that new task works great.

So I deleted all old tasks and recreated them and now everything works great.

Luckily I was present when that problem occurred but next time it might be the other way.

There was no error in the code since the script worked great when I run it directly using a browser.
I put cflog at the beginning of the scripts but there was no log since tasks never run those scripts.

Any ideas why my scheduled tasks stopped and why they worked great once I deleted and recreated them?

Comment: I used to have the same problem when I was using ColdFusion 8 a few years back. I never figured out a real solution. I ended up deleting and re-creating each scheduled task.

Comment: Does restarting the ColdFusion service get them going again?

Comment: @Miguel-F : Next time i'll try that but I don't think that is the solution of my problem.
It is easier to restart Coldfusion rather than creating 15 tasks all over again, that is truth, but I'd like to fix Coldfusion server from stopping my tasks.

Comment: True but you will most likely not be able to fix the issue because it is internal to the ColdFusion code. You are running an outdated version of ColdFusion so your only option is to be sure that you are at least running the most up-to-date code base for that version and see if it fixes the issue. If not, then you are out of luck because Adobe no longer supports it.